# Facebook app permissions in android

Tags: android, facebook, permissions, facebook-opengraph

I have a facebook app what posts video.watches actions to a user.
My problem is that I can't post it to a user who is not a developer or a tester or one of those special roles. Sandbox Mode is Disabled.
When the user want to use the application at first time it asks for permissions but in the android app appear the dialog: "Using this app requires: Your basic info   Your photos" but the Preview Login Dialog "THIS APP WILL RECEIVE: Your basic info Your activities..." so on what i defined at the permissions.
Can somebody tell me if i missed something or how can i ask for the defined permitions?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ask for publish type permissions the very first time you authorize the user.

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/upgrading-from-2.0-to-3.0/

And the note:

"Note: In the new SDK, you may ask only for read permissions when you first open a session. You should not prompt your user for publish permissions until the time at which they are actually publishing an action to Facebook. This increases user trust, and also the likelihood that your user will choose to publish stories from your app. To request further permissions, use Session.openForRead or Session.openForPublish."